# how to bind onchange event defined in a select menu in jquery call function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, xhtml, bind

i'm trying to implement clone select menu using the following plugin:

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/index.html

https://github.com/afEkenholm/ScrollectBox/blob/master/js/ScrollectBox/jquery.scrollectbox.js

but i'm unable to bind `onchange` event defined in the following select menu in jquery call function.

```
    <select onchange="function(this);" id="selector" class="selection" >
    <option value="" selected="Select Topic">Select Topic</option> 
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Drink">Drink</option>
    </select>
```

how can i bind `onchange="function(this);"` in the following call function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
   $(".selection").scrollectBox({
    preset: 'dropdown',
    numVisibleOptions: 4,
    scrollInterval: 150, 
    scrollOn: 'hover'
    });
});
</script>
```

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use chaining in jQuery.

```js
$(".selection").scrollectBox({
    preset: 'dropdown',
    numVisibleOptions: 4,
    scrollInterval: 150, 
    scrollOn: 'hover'
}).on('change', function() {
    // this
});
```